# netsh reset caused net to fail with VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, netsh

So I ran the these lines to fix making a hotspot (would not assign IP address).

```
netsh winsock reset catalog 
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
```

After this, the net works fine. But when I connect with my VPN (IKEv2 - windows 10 VPN), sites like youtube, google does not respond in a "new session" (ie. This site can’t be reached www.google.com took too long to respond).

If the site has been cached before and accessing it later with VPN works fine. Few other sites works without caching like tunein.com

Other devices I have works fine with this VPN, so I dont believe its the server issue.

Any ideas what might be the cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by adjusting the MTU size for the VPN interface.

using cmd in adminstrator. type `ping www.google.com -f -l 1492`

Keep Decreasing the number "1492" until the result is not fragmented.

With the largest number you can successfully, add 28 to it.  (ping worked with 1344, add 28 to get 1372) Thats your MTU number

Next, ensure you VPN is connected and type `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface`. Copy your VPN interface name.

Type `netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1492 store=persistent`. In place of 'Local Area Connection' enter you VPN interface and the replace 1492 with your MTU recommended size.